# Leaving postfix 'mydomain' & 'hostname' empty in this scenario

Tags: centos, postfix, vps, email-server, dovecot

I have a VPS server that only deals with email hosting. This server does not have any designated domain name pointing to it. Its only one VPS with one IP address.

I am running CentOS 6.5 Minimal, 32bit with Postfix and Dovecot installed. This is currently what my `etc/postfix/main.cf` looks like (for domain/hosting attributes).

```
# INTERNET HOST AND DOMAIN NAMES
#
# The myhostname parameter specifies the internet hostname of this
# mail system. The default is to use the fully-qualified domain name
# from gethostname(). $myhostname is used as a default value for many
# other configuration parameters.
#
myhostname =   
#myhostname =

# The mydomain parameter specifies the local internet domain name.
# The default is to use $myhostname minus the first component.
# $mydomain is used as a default value for many other configuration
# parameters.
#
mydomain =     
# SENDING MAIL
#
# The myorigin parameter specifies the domain that locally-posted
# mail appears to come from. The default is to append $myhostname,
# which is fine for small sites.  If you run a domain with multiple
# machines, you should (1) change this to $mydomain and (2) set up
# a domain-wide alias database that aliases each user to
# user@that.users.mailhost.
#
# For the sake of consistency between sender and recipient addresses,
# myorigin also specifies the default domain name that is appended
# to recipient addresses that have no @domain part.
#
#myorigin = $myhostname
myorigin = $mydomain
```

As you might have noticed, both `myhostname` & `mydomain` fields are empty. The reason for this is, the server doesn't really have a domain or hostname. What should I be doing in this case?

I have an `M` record pointing to `mail.my-domain.tld` and `MX` record pointing to `mail.my-domain.tld`

Can I use `mail.my-domain.tld` for both as `mydomain =` and `myhostname =` in `main.cf`? Because `my-domain.tld` is pointing to another VPS with another IP, which takes care of only web hosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default your mail server should accept email sent to its hostname, in your `mydestination` parameter you enter what domains you are receiving email for, so that would be `my-domain.tld` in your example and you can set `myhostname`, `mydomain` to one of the domains.

This is independent of your MX record, that record (which can be anything) points to a domain name which should resolve to the IP of your server (A record), you probably don't need to change it.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have over 10 domains, for which I am using this server to host all their emails? Can I put all those domains in `mydomain` & `myhostname` filed?

Comment: Sorry, mixed up mydomain and mydestination, edited the answer. So yes, you can put many mydestination domains separated my commas